# Converting equation to Cartesian coordinates

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble figuring out how to convert this equation to Cartesian coordinates. Sorry if I didn't format my question correctly, this is my first time using this site. Any help would be appreciated!
$$r = \frac{1}{2\cos(\theta)+3\sin(\theta)}$$

Answer (score 5):

If we multiply both sides with $2\cos(\theta)+3\sin(\theta)$ we obtain
$2r\cos(\theta)+3r\sin(\theta) = 1$. Since $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ we can rewrite this to $2x+3y=1$.

Comment: Thanks! The problem wants me to actually find the coordinates and describe the resulting curve. Would I just put that equation into slope intercept form?

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem even requires that, since 'describe the resulting curve' is a little vague. It couldn't hurt I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If 
$$r = \frac{1}{2\cos(\theta)+3\sin(\theta)}$$

then

$$2r\cos(\theta) + 3r\sin(\theta) = 1$$

Now remember what $x$ and $y$ are in terms of $r$ and $\sin(\theta), \cos(\theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

To go between polar coordinates and Cartesian coordinates, you can use that
$$\begin{align}
x &= r\cos(\theta) \\
y &= r\sin(\theta) \\
r^2 &= x^2 + y^2 
\end{align}
$$
So you can start by rewriting your equation as
$$
r[2\cos(\theta) + 3\sin(\theta)] = 1.
$$